# Xcode 10 Realm Swift "Module compiled with Swift 4.1.2 cannot be imported by the Swift 4.2 compiler"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm, xcode10

I just updated to Xcode 10 but can't make my project compile because of Realm.

When I use `import RealmSwift` I have this issue:

> Module compiled with Swift 4.1.2 cannot be imported by the Swift 4.2
>   compiler

I use Cocoapod and updated my pods. I have the last version of RealmSwift which is supposed to be Xcode 10 compatible. In the preferences the CLT is set to Xcode 10. In my project settings the language is set to Swift 4.

```
Using Realm (3.10.0)
Using RealmSwift (3.10.0)
```

I tried:

- clean project and build folder
- remove Realm from pods, build project then re-add
- delete derived data

Here's my podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
workspace 'ProjectName'
use_frameworks!
platform :ios, '10.0'
#deduplicate_targets: 'false'
inhibit_all_warnings!

def sharedPods
    pod 'TwitterKit'
    #pod 'TwitterCore'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'RealmSwift'
end

target 'ProjectName' do
    sharedPods

    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit'

    target 'ProjectNameTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        pod 'TwitterKit'
    end
end

target 'ProjectNameExtension' do
    sharedPods
end

post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.2'
        end
    end
end
```

I also tried removing the last part or changing with Swift 4.0 and even Swift 3.2.

I already saw similar questions on SOF but any reply worked for me.

Comment: Wow, I dealt with this yesterday, and it was a bitch. I'm sure there is a better way of solving this, but I removed all Pods, migrated my base code to 4.2, reinstalled the Pods, but ensured the Podfile was set to Swift 4.2. Took me forever. Hopefully there is a better way.

Comment: I'm removing all pods messing with my project and installing them manually for now. I will migrate to Swift 4.2 after that. Might try cocoapod again if you tell me it'w working after that. Thanks.

Comment: @MarieDm je suis dans cette galère également. When you say you removed all Pods, how did you get your app to build without them?! I'd like to migrate my code base to 4.2 as well but it won't unless it builds. Ton aide sera grandement appréciée !

Comment: I installed them the old way, by importing the libraries manually. BAsically you just drag and drop the files in your project.